# How to put nested if and for loops into one line in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I put the following into one line for an if statement?

```
for g_id in gene_ids:
    # start one liner from here onward
   if g_id in actual_isoforms:
      pairs = [tup for tup in actual_isoforms[g_id]]
      for p in pairs:
          if p == (t_id, str(num)):
              iso_id = p[0]
              iso_num = p[1]
              total = check_exon_num[iso_id]
```

I've tried this, but it says 'tup' is not defined:

```
if (g_id in actual_isoforms) and [p == (t_id, str(num)) for p in tup for tup in actual_isoforms[g_id]]:
```

Also `actual_isoforms` is a dictionary with a list of tuples. So 'pairs' are the list values and `p` is each tuple in that list.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to turn into a list comprehension. You aren't creating a list here, i.e. what exactly is ###STUFF

Comment: Are you forming a list?

Comment: Can you provide an example of `actual_isoforms` and the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `### STUFF` has no assignments:

```
if g_id in actual_isoforms:
    result = [### STUFF for tup in actual_isoforms[g_id] if tup == (t_id, str(num))]
```

This is where it went wrong in your try in list comprehension:

```
 for p in tup for tup in actual_isoforms[g_id]
```

`p` and `tup` in your expanded loop is referring to the *same* thing. There's only one loop as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

```py
pairs = [tup for tup in actual_isoforms[g_id] if tup == (t_id, str(num))]
```

So you can have a regular list comprehension with some `if condition_expression` appended to it. So you get `[x for x in iterable if condition_expression]` where `condition_expression` decides whether the element should be in included in the resulting list.

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, rather than just the code itself

Comment: Hi Thanks for sharing your answer. Please also add comment to clarify your answer/code.